# initwindow crashes program

Tags: c++, header, mingw, bgi

I have another problem with my graphics.h installation. It just won't work. I've tried a lot of different versions but none seem to work correctly on my win10 PC.
I'm currently using [these](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/) graphics.h librays.
My code is:

```
    //#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
//using namespace std;

int main()
{

    initwindow(1000,1000);
}
```

Every time I hit compile my program crashes! I'm using code::blocks with the mingw compiler.

Comment: How can you say "Everytime i hit compile my program crashes" since you **are compiling** your program and hasn't even build yet.

Comment: Dude i mean it finishes copiling and then executes and crashes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CodeBlocks as you're compiler:

1. Download WinBGIm from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/
2. Put the graphics.h and winbgim.h files in the *include* folder of your compiler directory.
3. Put the libbgi.a in your *lib* folder of your compiler directory.
4. Open CodeBlocks then Settings >> Compiler and Debugger >> Linker Settings.
5. Click *Add* then link and browse for the *libbgi.a* file.
6. In right part (i.e linker options) type commands
       - lbgi  -lgdi32  -lcomdlg32  -luuid  -loleaut32  -lole32
7. Click *Ok*

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You shouldn't post link-only answers which point to a screenshot. You should at least describe the basic steps to solve the problem.

Comment: I summarized it. Sorry, just joined this community.